# crear una consulta en sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

hola amigos es que tengo una consulta en mysql que es la siguiente y me funciona bien.

```
SELECT * FROM executables inner join products_has_executables on executables.idExecutable = products_has_executables.executableIdExecutable where executables.platformIdPlatform = 1 and products_has_executables.productIdProduct = 1 and products_has_executables.executableIdExecutable = 1;
```

y tengo mi codigo en nodejs sequelize de la siguiente manera.

```
const ExecutableByProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const executableByProduct = await executables.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: products_has_executables,
                }
            ]
        }
        );
        res.json({ executableByProduct });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
}
```

error que me tira el sequelize:

```
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: products_has_executables is not associated to executables!
```

la verdad e intentado de varias maneras me gustaria ver la consulta que hace sequelize para ver si lo que ocurre es que se esta ejecutando mal la consulta o hay un problema en node, pero se supone que si existe una relación ya que si funciona en mysql pero en node no.

Comment: Coloca la definición de tus relaciones entre las tablas `executables` y `products_has_executables`, principalmente tus funciones de asociación.

Comment: hola efectivamente era error mio, pues resulta que me tocaba crear el modelo directamento de product_has_executable y no dejarlo por medioo de belongsToMany ya que pensaba que con solo eso se relacionaba.